# Accessing url helpers in mailer class and views in Spree application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I want to use one of the url helpers in a mailer class defined in my Spree application. So i did the following

```
Spree::CartonMailer.class_eval do
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end
```

This allows me to access the url helper in mailer class but then any url helper i call in the view or partials does not work. How can i make the url helpers work in both mailer class and the views/partials as well ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a variable with routes, like:

```
my_routes = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

And use in ou code like:

```
my_routes.root_path
my_routes.resource_path
...
```

No need to `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`